# How do the Discord Orb and Headshot multiplier interact?

Tags: overwatch

Another question has addressed how the Discord Orb and the Caduceus Damage Boost interact, but stacking is inconsistent in Overwatch.  So far, it appears that unlike bonuses are multiplicative, while like bonuses are additive if they stack at all.  But I'm unsure if that is truly the case across the board, and I'm also uncertain if that extends to elements which are not character abilities.

Can anyone help clear up how the 50% bonus from Discord and the 100% bonus from eligible headshots (150% for Widowmaker) stack? Is the total damage 250%, or 300%?

Answer (score 5):

Damage modifier stacking is perfectly consistent in Overwatch. The Discord Orb would increase by 50% the 200% damage from a headshot, resulting in 300% damage.

In the image below, I've hit both Training Bots with one headshot each.

[image: Image with proof]

The normal headshot deals 3.6 bars of damage, while the Discord headshot deals 5.4 bars of damage.

Comment: This is not quite correct, as Mercy's damage boost, according to what I've found, stacks additively and not multiplicitively.  So either it's not perfectly consistent (which is frankly for the better so far as tuning abilities goes), or these elements stack additively.  It would be best, I think, if someone were to test this (or perhaps you have a source?)

Comment: @NerdyCanuck You're confusing "consistent" with "identical", I think.

Comment: Not if you're going to use the term "perfectly consistent" without qualification.  As you've stated it presently, you're suggesting that damage modifier stacking is perfectly consistent with all other damage modifier stacking, rather than with a rule governing damage modifier stacking (such as the one I suggested might be in place in the question itself).   In any case, some form of testing or sourcing would be appreciated over a "just so" answer.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck There you go.

Comment: I can't tell from this image if that's a 150% increase or a 200% increase

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The normal headshot deals 3.6 bars of damage, while the Discord headshot deals 5.4 bars of damage. I'm not sure where the confusion is.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck Mercy beams stack additively with each other, but the total boost from mercy beams is multiplicative with other buffs.

Comment: @NerdyCanuck Continuing DCShannon's thought: Are you claiming that Mercy's damage beam stacks additively with the headshot bonus? If not then "perfectly consistent" is correct.

Comment: @DCShannon It's worth noting that this is going to change with the next patch, making Mercy's buff no longer stack with itself, just like Orb of Discord, which I guess makes it even more consistent.